# What could effect the usability of the width attribute?

Tags: css, attributes, width, containers

I have a space of code that I've written for a client. It works perfectly in a test page, however it doesn't work when it's put on his actual page. The code is here...

http://jsfiddle.net/ugngp7ft/1/

```
.hidden_textfield {

    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    background-color: transparent;
    font-family: inherit;
    font-size: inherit;

}
```

I've figured out that the issue is an inability to set the "width" attribute of the text box. Is there a way to use that attribute without going through the mountain of CSS that he already has to figure out why it can't be set? What would even cause the width attribute to have no effect on a text box? Thanks.

Comment: It works even without `display:block` - http://jsfiddle.net/ugngp7ft/2/

Comment: Nope. Figured I might try something like that. It didn't work either. I have absolutely no idea what would cause that to happen, but it's literally thousands of lines of CSS to go through. I just need to find a work around.

Comment: *EDIT*  When you posted that code that turned the textboxes blue, I pasted it into the actual CSS file. Now I'm noticing that it's not turning blue.  The class is definitely declared, and the CSS file is definitely link. I quadruple checked both those things, and if I remove the CSS file the container gets messed up...

Answer (score 0):

Completely exiting Chrome and reopening made it work on the main page. Go figure. Thanks for the time.

Comment: Didn't think CSS was cached?

Comment: oh yeah, it does get cached 100%. if normal reload didn't work try "hard reload chrome" or go incognito mode for quick testing.

Comment: That's good to know. I'm sure I've probably been ironing out bugs that aren't there forever. Thanks.